VScode cached path to library
I have an issue with starting a project with vsCode. After updating ImageMagick version with brew Now path should be like this:
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/{new-version}/lib'.
I constantly get error like this:
There is a provided start script:
Build Error: go build -o /Users/PanBorewicz/Development/platform/cmds/platform/__debug_bin3663727529 -gcflags all=-N -l ./main.go # command-line-arguments /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1 ld: warning: search path '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-29_1/lib' not found ld: library 'MagickWand-7.Q16HDRI' not found clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (exit status 1)

Run configuration is:
{
        "name": "All services",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmds/platform/main.go",
        "args": ["run", "all"],
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.internal.env"
    },

I try:
reinstalling vscode and remove caches
reinstalling brew and delete chaches
reinstalling imagemagick and delete chaces
changing back name of the folder
refresh /.zshrc
I have the same problem in december 2022 but i don't remember how I solve it.
If topic duplicater, realy sorry i found multiple ones connected to X-code.
Thank you.
